# reading.table() retrieves data with 0 rows

Tags: r, dataframe, read.table

I'm reading a text file using the next line

`>id<-(read.table("ids.txt",sep=",", header=TRUE, colClasses="character"))`

which looks like

```
"AC1000_Robusta_6278510_QFwXLwHOOp.dx","AC1001_LAOS_6278554_7pEHoew2PJ.dx","AC1002_Guinea_6278607_ac5B1C9jLt.dx","AC1003_Arabica_6279629_PtdVFPNt5I.dx","AC1004_Arabiga_6278662_KrDU9wGVXB.dx"
```

I can retrieve the data, but I see this line at the end of the data

> <0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

the class of the data is data.frame with 0 rows and 956 columns, but what I really want is a list of characters how I can change that?

Thanks for your help

Comment: What does `"ids.txt"` look like? Can you give 2 or 3 example lines indicative of the data that isn't imported properly?

Comment: yes, actually also retrieves the data

Comment: You don't have a header/table in your data. Just one long list of comma separated values. Try `scan("ids.txt",what=character(),sep=",")` If you look at `read.table`'s code, you'll see a lot of the hard work is done by `scan()` anyway

Comment: I could resolved the right way was id<-as.character(read.table("ids.txt",sep=",", header=FALSE, fill=TRUE, colClasses="character"))

Comment: @JessicaMedina - just use `scan` to go textfile --> character vector. It's simpler, more direct, and designed for exactly what you are doing. As it is, you are going textfile --> call `scan` --> rearrange to data.frame --> rearrange to character vector. You also don't need `fill=TRUE` as it makes no difference here.